# Japanese storing SQL Server and display PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, cjk

I have problem with Japanese Characters. I want to store Japanese Characters into a SQL Server database. When I try to display in Terminal it's good but when I try in HTML page Japanese characters are replace with question marks. I don't understand why it's work in console and not in web browser.

I try to change collation for the database, change charset to html page, without any effect

How can I fix that?

Thanks

Comment: Voting to re-open because the marked duplicate only has advice for MySQL and PHP, not MS-SQL Server.

Comment: Actually he seems to be having trouble to display that data in HTML. The insert/select on SQL-Server seems correct. Probably charset and/or font issue.